# Nominatim address locator does't give longitude

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, geocoding, nominatim

I'm trying to geocode my addresses based on this tutorial:

http://www.digital-geography.com/geocoding-addresses-in-arcgis-the-other-approach/#.VzMq_IR97Rb

But Whenever I use Nominatim geocoder it gives me this error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'longitude'
```

The process works fine with Google geocoder. Doesn't Nominatim recognize longitudes or what? When I checked the address from my CSV file in OSM, I see that the address is not a point, its a house so a polygon. Can this be a reason it doesn't recognize just one longitude?

Comment: What is your GET request?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. I used the script almost exactly as written in the link.
Update: The script now somehow magically works with Nominatim. I'm not sure what changed.